Can a Discord server onboarding process involves external api calls for user validation?
I work for a well known company and we are looking for a way to ensure that only users of our website with an account in good standing can join and remain on our discord server. I am having trouble finding a way to do that.

One way would be to check the the member when they join via the guildMemberAdd event. How you correlate a Discord member to a site user is up to you.
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
   const isAllowed = ... // call to api

   if (!isAllowed) {
      member.kick()
         .catch(console.error);
   }
});

If you need to do checks on existing members, fetch them and iterate through them:
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch("guild id");
const members = await guild.members.fetch();

for (const member of members) {
   const isAllowed = ... // call to api

   if (!isAllowed) {
      member.kick()
         .catch(console.error);
   }
}

